# Javascript memory usage in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

I try to profile memory usage in nodejs (0.10.35), I created 2 files below and run with node --expose-gc

var a and var b are initialized as empty string

A for loop is run to make a and b bigger

setInterval prints out the memory usage every 1 second

The x >> 20 operator is equivalent to Math.floor(x/1024/1024) to give the result in MB

```js
//file 1.js

var a = '', b = '', n = 0;
var i = 10000000; for (;i;i--) {a += i; b += i;}}

setInterval(function(){
    var m = process.memoryUsage();
    console.log(++n,m.rss>>20,m.heapTotal>>20,m.heapUsed>>20);  
},1000);

setTimeout(function(){  
    global.gc();
    console.log('1st garbage collect');
},2500);

setTimeout(function(){
    a = null;
    console.log('var a cleared');   
},5000);

setTimeout(function(){
    global.gc();
    console.log('2nd garbage collect');
},7500);

//file 2.js is similar to file 1 except that var a and var b are changed at separate loops
var i = 10000000; for (;i;i--) {a += i;}
var i = 10000000; for (;i;i--) {b += i;}
```

I got the results from console

```
     1.js                  2.js
1    1098 1073 1069        1407 1378 1375
2    1098 1073 1069        1407 1378 1375
     1st garbage collect
3    1098 1073 1069        715 696 688
4    1098 1073 1069        715 696 688
     var a cleared
5    1098 1073 1069        715 696 688
6    1098 1073 1069        715 696 688
7    1098 1073 1069        715 696 688
     2nd garbage collect
8    19   11   1           20  12  1
```

My questions are:

1. The a.length and b.length is only ~ 65 MB, why the memory usage ~1000 MB in file 1.js and ~1400 MB in file 2.js
2. After the 1st garbage collection, wouldn't var b be collected but it looks like the memory usage is still > 1000 MB for file 1.js, but ~700 MB in file 2.js?

After the 2nd garbage collection, the memory drops to < 20 MB, as expected. Am I looking at something wrong here?

Comment: Dude, can you explain this at this time?

Answer (score 0):

you have two braces

```
var i = 10000000; for (;i;i--) {a += i; b += i;}}//<-----here
```

maybe that's why the functions are misbehaving.